# Intellij deleted my project files - how to recover?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was working on a project in Intellij when my laptop suddenly turned off completely(I unplugged the charger and apparently the battery loses contact if you move the computer). I'm sure I saved before unplugging. Now that I launch Intellij, I noticed several unpleasant changes:

1. The IDE doesn't remember recent projects; it didn't open my project straight up after I launched it as it usually did before.
2. Project files are all gone, all that remains is an .iml file.
3. The color theme changed back to white, even though I switched it to black.
4. Most disturbingly, local history appears to be wiped, there's nothing there save for the .iml file.

In the light of these circumstances, I have these questions:

1. What the hell happened? Why did all my files disappear? They were all saved, so how could they just vanish?
2. Is there any way to recover them or did Intellij scrapped them so thoroughly they're gone?

Comment: Have you checked the folders where the project used to be?  IntelliJ saves automatically AFAIK so this should not have been the issue.

Comment: Yes, I can see all the classes buried in C:\Users\...\IdeaProjects\Legends\src\cz\kucharfida\legends, but can't seem to get Intellij to put them back in the project(or whatever the correct terminus technicus is).

Comment: Oh this is great news because it looks like your stuff is there.  Most likely the IntelliJ project file was corrupted during the black out.

Comment: Any way to auto-recover it? It's not a super huge project, but nevertheless I don't feel like starting a new project and copying it all over by hand.

Comment: Then you're not going to like my answer :-)  But seriously, it will only take you a few minutes to copy the source files into the new project.  Also, it might be risky to continue developing with a corrupted project.

Comment: For those that don't, this is all the more reason to backup your project directories. Personally I do this 'at least' once a day. I've had plenty fill of lost work in the past :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that one or more of the IntelliJ project files was corrupted during the sudden power off.  As a result, IntelliJ is not loading your project correctly.  I would approach this by creating a new project, with the same options as your first one, and then copying the source files over from the old location.

Comment: Ok, on an off chance I might avoid the copying; I just opened one of the classes, ready to copy away, but the IDE suddenly showed all the other folders and classes in the project view sidebar. It just doesn't detect compile time errors as it usually does. Is this a good sign?

Comment: I don't usually say "I don't know" on this site, but I'm actually going to say just that.  If you want to try to salvage the original project, you are free to do so, but do so at your own risk.  IntelliJ is great for fixing broken source files which don't compile, but it is not so good at fixing broken projects.

Comment: By the way, what language are you using (e.g. Java)?

Comment: Update, I think I found an easier way to do this: Start a new project from existing sources and just pass it the whole old project folder. It somehow sorts it out and the project now appears to be working correctly(can't test for compilation since it's riddled with errors).

Comment: This is great news.  But please check to make sure that the project has been created completely with nothing missing.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the project directory or folder. Go to 
**Local_History > Show_History**

From the list of history, Right click on the change you want to recover and choose **Revert**

Answer (score 0):

I had no power or issues, I just left my laptop in sleep with idea running, and now everything is gone.

This issue also happened to people here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206877445-Please-help-IntelliJ-11-just-deleted-all-my-files-?page=1#community_comment_204002510

For me, I was lucky that I could still recover/undelete these files using a tool like Recuva